# JavaScript "this" keyword and arrow function

Tags: javascript

Here *this* keyword which is in arrow function points to **obj**'s variable environment

```js
var greeting = 'hi';

const obj = {
  greeting: 'hey',

  fo() {
    const greeting = 'hola';
    
      const arrowFo = () => {
        console.log(this.greeting);
      };

      arrowFo();
  },
};

obj.fo(); //logs: hey
```

but in this new example it points to global object. I did not figure out what has changed? there is just added a new regular function fo2. Can anyone explain to me what is happening there? (I was anticipating that it would pointed to **fo2**'s local environment and would printed "hello") Thanks in advance

```js
var greeting = 'hi';

const obj = {
  greeting: 'hey',

  fo() {
    const greeting = 'hola';

    const fo2 = function () {
      const greeting = 'hello';

      const arrowFo = () => {
        console.log(this.greeting);
      };

      arrowFo();
    };
    fo2();
  },
};

obj.fo(); //logs: hi
```

Comment: That's one of the differences between using an arrow function vs a regular function

Comment: The `this` keyword never points to an "environment", it points to a *value* (typically an object). It refers to the `this` value in `fo2`, which is the global object since you called `fo2()` (not as a method).

Comment: `this` inside `foo2` refers to the `window` object and not the `obj` because of the way you have called `fo2`. Replace `fo2()` with `fo2.call(this);` and you will see the expected output.

Comment: @Yousaf That would still not print `hello` but `hey` which is present on `obj` since now `this` will be `obj`. I think the asker is confusing `const/let/var` declared variables being accessed via `this`.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I though OP expected "hey" as the output - thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrow functions have no this value in their scope, so you can access `this` value of the object. But Normal functions have this value in their scope, in this example `this` value of the normal function is globalThis or window. and it allows to you access the global scope. if you call `fo2` with `this` value of object instead of globalThis you get '"hey"'

```js
var greeting = 'hi';

const obj  = {
  greeting: 'hey',

  fo() {
    const greeting = 'hola';

    const fo2 = function () {
      const greeting = 'hello';

      const arrowFo = () => {
        console.log(this.greeting);
      };

      arrowFo();
    };
    fo2.call(this) // Use this instead of fo2()
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript the this object is really based on how you make your function calls.
the fo2() function is not binded in any object for this purpos it get the this of global context

you have to declare your function with the this like this :

```
var greeting = 'hi';

const obj = {
  greeting: 'hey',

  fo() {
    const greeting = 'hola';

     this.fo2 = function () {
      const greeting = 'hello';

      const arrowFo = () => {
        console.log(this.greeting);
      };

      arrowFo();
    };
    this.fo2();
  },
};

obj.fo(); //logs: hi
```

or use arrow function like this :

```
var greeting = 'hi';
const obj = {
  greeting: 'hey',
  fo() {
    const greeting = 'hola';
    fo2 =  () => {
      const greeting = 'hello';
      const arrowFo = () => {
        console.log(this.greeting);
      };
      arrowFo();
    };
    fo2();
    
  },
};
obj.fo();
```

Comment: is it correct explanation if I say:
arrow functions do not get their own 'this keyword'. Instead, if you use 'the this variable' in an arrow function, it will simply be the this keyword of the surrounding function. and in my example foo2(surrounding function) was pointed to global object as general regular function do. and that was why it printed "hi"

Comment: Yeah in the second function example the this of arrow function will be the this of the function surrounding wich is fo2() the problem is in fo2 function wich didn't get the this of obj because it's called with the global this

Comment: The solution is to make fo2 and arrow function to get the this of obj or to call it with this.fo2